# iTextSharp LGPLv2.Core fails to properly apply CSS in <style> tag

Tags: c#, itext

I am having an issue where my itextsharp cannot seem to properly parse and apply non-inline styles to my HTML, instead it renders the PDF only with the inline styles being correct, but it treats anything in  as a regular string.

After some research I saw that it has a stylesheet class, so I decided to remove my css inside of my  tag and try to add it to the page as follows:

```
var css = new StyleSheet();
                css.LoadStyle("h1", "text-align", "center");
                css.LoadStyle("h1", "text-transform", "uppercase");
                css.LoadStyle("h1", "text-align", "center");

                css.LoadStyle("h2", "text-align", "center");
                css.LoadStyle("h2", "text-transform", "uppercase");
                css.LoadStyle("h2", "text-align", "center");

                css.LoadStyle("h3", "text-align", "center");
                css.LoadStyle("h3", "text-transform", "uppercase");
                css.LoadStyle("h3", "text-align", "center");

                css.LoadStyle("marginBottomSmall", "margin-bottom", "10px");
                css.LoadStyle("tableTopAlign", "vertical-align", "top");

                css.LoadStyle("customBullet::before", "content", @"'\2022'");
                css.LoadStyle("customBullet::before", "padding-right", "0.5em");

                css.LoadStyle("customBullet", "display", "flex");

                css.LoadStyle("flexColumnContainer", "display", "flex");
                css.LoadStyle("flexColumnContainer", "flex-direction", "column");

                css.LoadStyle("tableDiv", "display", "table");

                css.LoadStyle("fixedWidthMed", "width", "325px");
                css.LoadStyle("fixedWidthMed", "display", "table-cell");

                css.LoadStyle("tableRow", "display", "table-row");

                css.LoadStyle("flexRowContainer", "display", "flex");
                css.LoadStyle("flexRowContainer", "flex-direction", "row");

                css.LoadStyle("forceULPadding", "padding-left", "20px");

                css.LoadStyle("SoapListNoBullets", "list-style", "none");

                css.LoadStyle("printable", "max-width", "800px");

                css.LoadStyle("bottomPadContent td", "padding-bottom", "10px");
                css.LoadStyle("bottomPadContent td", "vertical-align", "top");
```

I then tried to apply it to my HtmlWorker as follows:

```
            var htmlWorker = new HtmlWorker(doc);
            htmlWorker.Style = css;
```

However, after parsing it I do not not see it apply the styles at all. What is the correct way to do it? I see a lot of things about itextsharp, but they appear to be for a different version, and namely the full .NET framework, I am limited by the fact that it must be made for dotnet core instead.

Comment: Please don't use HtmlWorker. Use XMLWorker instead (iText 5), or even better, pdfHTML (iText 7). iText 7 most definitely works on .NET Core.

Comment: Gotcha, that's good to know. I assume then, since i don't even think the nuget version I am using has an XMLWorker, that it is probably best to just not use it at all

Comment: That is correct, iTextSharp 4.1.6 does not have XMLWorker. That was introduced somewhere in iText(Sharp) 5.